# Managing iOS core graphics bitmap contexts on the stack

Tags: ios, bitmap, core-graphics, uigraphicscontext

I can successfully create and use a Core Graphics bitmap context for background drawing as follows:

- call `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()` to create a new bitmap and make it the current context
- draw some content using the CG API
- periodically tell my view to call `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` outside of `drawRect()` and `setNeedsDisplay()`, then inside `drawRect()` I paint the image into the view
- finally call `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()` to tidy up the bitmap and remove it from the top of the stack.

All very good and it works fine, but **is there some way to manage this kind of graphics context on the stack?** It seems a bit weird having to rely on it remaining the current context throughout the whole process... *I mean, what would you do if your app needed to periodically display updates on two different bitmaps that each had their own context?*

At first I thought that I could just use `UIGraphicsPushContext()` and `UIGraphicsPopContext()`, but that stops the bitmap context working, and indeed the [UIKit Functions Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions) says you should not do it:

> [...] The drawing environment is pushed onto the graphics context stack immediately.
>
> While the context created by this function is the current context, you can call the UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext function to retrieve an image object based on the current contents of the context. When you are done modifying the context, you must call the UIGraphicsEndImageContext function to clean up the bitmap drawing environment and remove the graphics context from the top of the context stack. **You should not use the UIGraphicsPopContext function to remove this type of context from the stack.**
>
> In most other respects, the graphics context created by this function behaves like any other graphics context. You can change the context by pushing and popping other graphics contexts. You can also get the bitmap context using the UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext function.

Any ideas...? It's not a problem as such, but I'd like to know if I'm missing something here...

Comment: Perhaps the way around this is to build the image using Core Graphics calls (something I don't yet understand how to do)

Answer (score 0):

As detailed in the Apple developer documentation, it is not possible to pop a `UIGraphicsImageContext` off the context stack.

If you do need to manipulate two bitmap contexts in parallel (or off the main thread) then this can be achieved by creating and manipulating them using Core Graphics API calls. Doing this is slightly more complex than using the UIGraphics API and requires you to manage the scaling between pixels and display points, but it's entirely do-able.